# Styling every node without affecting coordinate styles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a diagram and connect the nodes. Since i want to Place the labels above the lines I use `every node/.style={above=.4ex, anchor=base}`. However sometimes I draw `coordinates` at corners, so that I can connect multiple lines. However, these `coordinates` are `nodes` and thus are shifted by the `above` command.

Is there a `style` that affects **only** `nodes` (not `coordinates`) or **only** `coordinates` (not `nodes`)?

*update* Along the discussion to the awnser here is an example where I get by with setting above to 0 instead of a negative value

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[demo/.style={every node/.style={above=3 pt}}, every coordinate node/.style={above=0}]
   \draw[demo] (0, 0) -- node{Label} coordinate(c1) (1,0);
   \node at (c1) [red]{x};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: samble with overwriting above]

FULL CODE: (unnecessary headers included), [see it in action at writelatex](https://www.writelatex.com/183836pjczpg)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[demo/.style={every node/.style={above=3 pt}}, every coordinate node/.style={above=0}]
   \draw[demo] (0, 0) -- node{Label} coordinate(c1) (1,0);
   \node at (c1) [red]{x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra example.  However, when I compile it I don't get the output shown, both the Label and x are raised.  THis is even more clear when you replace `3pt` by `3cm`.  So additive behaviour is still present in this case.  For reference my `tikz` verison is "2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)"

Comment: @AndrewSwann: please check out https://www.writelatex.com/183836pjczpg or try the full code I posted in the awnser (I was to lazy to strip down all the headers, but it will compile fine on writelatex). P.S.: my local tikz version is `tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the full code.  It is the use of the `positioning` library that it is changing the behaviour to being non-additive.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: you found that out by try and error? DO you know why it does so/ how it changes the behaviour of above?

Comment: It was by experiment.  That this affects the behaviour of above in this way, seems to be in direct contradiction with a statement in the pgfmanual on page 185.  Anyway I have added an extra example to my answer to show this behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`coordinate`s are `shape`s and for each `shape` there is an `every shape node` that can be set.  For example,

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={red},every coordinate node/.style={above=1cm}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \draw (0,0) node {\( O \)}-- (2,2) node {\( X \)};
  \draw[blue] (A) node {\( A \)} -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here, in the opposite to you use case, coordinate nodes are shifted, whereas other nodes are left in place.

In your use case, you can cancel the `above` on the coordinate by shifting it back:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={above=2ex,anchor=base},every coordinate node/.style={above=-2ex,anchor=base}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \draw (0,0) node {\( O \)}-- (2,2) node {\( X \)};
  \draw[very thick,red] (A) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Sample use case]

*EDIT* As Andrew Stacey notes this additive behave of the `above` command is unexpected.  However, it is not often we see it.  In fact if you use two `above`'s in the same node you do indeed see the additive effect:

[image: Additive sample]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \draw[red] (A) -- (1,0);
  \draw (A) node[anchor=base,above=2ex,above=1ex] {\( x \)};
  \draw[blue] (A) node[anchor=base,above=3ex] {\( O \)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here we place `O` with its baseline `3ex` above the origin, and place `x` at with baseline at `above=2ex,above=1ex` from the origin and obtain the same positioning.

*FURTHER EDIT* If the `tikz` library positioning is loaded, then the additive behaviour of `above` no longer occurs.  The last `above` directive is the one used, and an `above` for `coordinate` will override an `above` for `every node`:

[image: Sample positioning output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={above=2ex,anchor=base},every coordinate node/.style={above=-2ex,anchor=base}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \draw (0,0) node {\( O \)}-- (2,2) node {\( X \)};
  \draw[very thick,red] (A) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \draw[red] (A) -- (1,0);
  \draw (A) node[anchor=base,above=2ex,above=1ex] {\( x \)};
  \draw[red] (A) node[anchor=base,above=10cm,above=1ex] {\( \quad x \)};
  \draw[blue] (A) node[anchor=base,above=3ex] {\( O \)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is above really cumulative?

Comment: @AndrewStacey I only have empirical evidence: putting the coordinate style to `above=0pt` in the second example gives a red line starting higher than `O`.  An explanation of why it behaves like this would be nice to have.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Double above example now added showing additivity.

Comment: The `above` and `below` keys (and all the others) not only set the anchor, but when a length is given use the basic layer transformations `\pgftransformxshift` and `\pgftransformyshift`, so effects will be additive. Thus, `above=2ex,above=1ex` result in `\pgftransformyshift{2ex}` followed by `\pgftransformyshift{1ex}`. The transformations are applied just before the node is typeset.

Comment: @MarkWibrow : In my case I miss to see the additivity: I have a style `umlTransition/.style={-angle 60, every node/.style={above=.4 ex, anchor=base}}` and apply this to `draw` commands, for the coordinates I fixed the application by adding `[above=0]` to every coordinate, e.g.: `\draw[umlTransition, umlShortened] (joinDiscard) |- coordinate[above=0] (discardCorner) (fetchJoinCorner);`. For some reason above seems to be none additive in this case (it fixed my issue). Do you have an explanation (I assume it has something todo with how tikz manages styles and dirket option, but am quite unsure)

Comment: @AndrewSwann I hope my edit is alright, I observer that I get by without negative shifts in this case, I hope on [Mark Wibrow][http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow] to solve the mistery.

Comment: @MarkWibrow I added a minimal example at the bottom of Andrew Swann`s awnser to demonstrate

Comment: @ted I have not seen your edit, other reviewers have rejected it first.  You can always add it to the bottom of your question instead. From what you write in your comment, your `every node/.style` only applies to `\draw[umlTransition]` commands, so the coordinates are unaffected.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: thanks for the hint. I added the example to my question. Just to point it out: the coordinate in my comment is inside the `path` that is drawn with `\draw[umlTransition]` (`\draw[umlTransition] (1,2) coordinate (example)`), but for ease of reading have a look at the changed question.

Answer (score 3):

I want to propose a few other possibilities.

1. Use `label`s. That’s why they exist.
2. If your “labels” only use the `rectangle` shape (the default one) and the `rectangle` shape is only used for label, you can use the `every rectangle node` style.
3. The last possibility introduces the ability to use a `every not coordinate node` that gets applied when the node is not a `coordinate`. The shape name has to be specified by `every not`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  every not/.code=%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@node@begin@hook\expandafter{%
      \tikz@node@begin@hook
      \def\pgf@tempa{#1}%
      \ifx\tikz@shape\pgf@tempa\else
        \tikzset{every not \pgf@tempa\space node/.try}%
      \fi
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[demo/.style={every label/.style={label distance=3pt, label position=above}}]
   \draw[demo] (0, 0) -- coordinate[label=Label] (c1) (1,0);
   \node at (c1) [red]{x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[demo/.style={every rectangle node/.style={above=3pt}}]
   \draw[demo] (0, 0) -- node {Label} coordinate (c1) (1,0);
   \node at (c1) [red]{x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[demo/.style={every not=coordinate, every not coordinate node/.style={above=3pt}}]
   \draw[demo] (0, 0) -- node {Label} coordinate (c1) (1,0);
   \node at (c1) [red]{x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]